# Как настроить триггер в Quartz.Net для выполнения несработавших задач

Tags: c#, asp, quartz

Пытаюсь "приготовить" кварц на ASP Net Core. Делаю так:

```
builder.Services.AddQuartz(q => 
{
    q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();
    q.UsePersistentStore(x => 
    {
        x.UseJsonSerializer();
        x.UsePostgres(x =>
        {
           x.UseDriverDelegate<PostgreSQLDelegate>();
           x.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        });
   });
   q.UseDefaultThreadPool(tp =>
   {
       tp.MaxConcurrency = 10;
   });
   q.ScheduleJob<TestJob>(trigger => 
   {
       trigger.WithIdentity("TestTrigger")                    
              .WithCronSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(12, 00)
              .WithMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed();
   }).StartNow());
});
```

Ожидание: Приложение запущено в 11:00, затем "упало" в 11:30, а восстановилось в 12:10. Запланированная задача выполнится после запуска.

Реальность: Задача не выполняется.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33010182/12888024

Comment: @aepot, пробовал с разными значениями, не сработало.